# Can I change SQL/schema queries in Talend studio generated code?

Tags: sql, talend

I have 1000 of tables in a database, I want to pull the data from database tables using Talend studio DI tools , instead of creating job for each table I want to change queries and file path only in generated code, Is is possible ?

Comment: You want to pull data from database and create flat files for all the tables?

Comment: Also which database and OS are you using. And can you connect to your db from os?

Comment: @Utsav, I want to pull data from oracle and netezza db, dump in csv files, I am using Linux(Ubunutu 14.04 LTS), Yes I am able to connect. I have created a single job which is working perfectly and able to generate a flat CSV file.

Comment: If you can connect to db from your os, i would suggest you to write generic script to pull data and dump in files. You can pass table names and file names to it and it should create csv files for you. Not sure on talend side.

Comment: @SANDHYALALKUMAR edit your question and specify what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage Are you using Talend Open Studio ?